# Extracting just needed css from materialize.css

Tags: css

I am trying to extract just the css needed from materialize.css to use the navigation buttons from the following page:

https://jsfiddle.net/5fqg98xd

I tried extracting the css from the delete button:

```
<div id="btnDelete"><i id="btnDeleteI"></i></div>
```

But the button does not work at all now and the hover over does not change its color.

```
#btnDelete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

#btnDeleteI {
    border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-left-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-right-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Material-Design-Icons;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    height: 55px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    line-height: 55.5px;
    outline-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    speak: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 55.5px;
    z-index: 0;
    perspective-origin: 27.75px 27.5px;
    transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    transform-origin: 27.75px 27.5px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-top: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-right: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-bottom: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-left: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal normal normal 24px / 55.5px Material-Design-Icons;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}/*#btnDeleteI*/
```

Any help extracting just the needed css for creating the navigation buttons from above link would be greatly appreciated.

**Questions:**
Why is it that you need to extract the css, why dont you just use the whole materialize.css file?  I cannot use the whole file because it is causing unnecessary modifications to the rest of the page that cannot be modified.

**Update # 1**

I tried uncss as suggested below.  This broke materialize.css and buttons no longer display/function properly.

**Update # 2**

[SnappySnippet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snappysnippet/blfngdefapoapkcdibbdkigpeaffgcil?hl=en) did a much better job at css extraction than uncss since it allows you to inspect the desired element and then just displays the relevant css.  But even SnappySnippet was not 100% exact on extracting the css from materialize.css and caused the buttons to loose their icons and hovering effects.

**Update #3**

I am opening a bounty for this question.  Please provide a working [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/5fqg98xd/) eliminating all unneeded css from materialize.css for bounty award.  For a working completed project, the reference to the external resource "materialize.css" should be gone and all css pertaining to the navigation buttons should be in the local css section of jsfiddle.  Here is a complete starting point:

https://jsfiddle.net/5fqg98xd/

Also, everything should work as it does now.  For example buttons should change style color when selected as they do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is everything working with 280 css line of code

Visit https://jsfiddle.net/1dq74z80/

sorry for the above fiddle the fiddle widthout materilize css link is https://jsfiddle.net/toadalskii/tx6pzph7/

or

get the code below

```
.teal {
  background-color: #009688 !important;
}

.teal.darken-2 {
  background-color: #00796b !important;
}

.orange {
  background-color: #ff9800 !important;
}

.orange.darken-2 {
  background-color: #f57c00 !important;
}


.btn-large, .btn-floating{
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.btn-large:hover, .btn-floating:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.material-icons {
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
     -moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
          font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Material-Design-Icons";
  src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.woff2") format("woff2"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.woff") format("woff"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.ttf") format("truetype"), url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.svg#Material-Design-Icons") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="mdi-"], [class*="mdi-"] {
  speak: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Material-Design-Icons";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
          transform: translate(0, 0);
}

[class^="mdi-"]:before, [class*="mdi-"]:before {
  display: inline-block;
  speak: none;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

[class^="mdi-device-signal-cellular-"]:after, {
  opacity: .3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  speak: none;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

.mdi-device-signal-cellular-null:after {
    content: "";
}

.mdi-action-speaker-notes:before {
    content: "\e677";
}

.mdi-editor-mode-edit:before {
    content: "\e7a4";
}

.mdi-maps-place:before {
    content: "\e899";
}

.mdi-social-share:before {
    content: "\e8ed";
}

.mdi-device-signal-cellular-null:before {
    content: "\e75f";
}

.mdi-action-delete:before {
    content: "\e621";
}

.mdi-content-add:before {
    content: "\e701";
}

.mdi-content-remove:before {
    content: "\e716";
}

/ new content */



.disabled.btn-large, .btn-floating.disabled, .btn-large.disabled, .btn-large:disabled, .btn-large:disabled, .btn-floating:disabled {
  background-color: #DFDFDF !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #9F9F9F !important;
  cursor: default;
}

.disabled.btn-large *, .btn-floating.disabled *, .btn-large.disabled *, .btn-large:disabled *, .btn-large:disabled *, .btn-floating:disabled * {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.disabled.btn-large:hover, .btn-floating.disabled:hover, .btn-large.disabled:hover, .btn:disabled:hover, .btn-large:disabled:hover, .btn-large:disabled:hover, .btn-floating:disabled:hover {
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
  color: #9F9F9F;
}

.btn i, .btn-large i, .btn-floating i, .btn-large i {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  line-height: inherit;
}
.btn-large {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #26a69a;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  transition: .2s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-floating {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 37px;
  height: 37px;
  line-height: 37px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #26a69a;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn-floating i {
  width: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 37px;
}

.btn-floating:hover {
  background-color: #26a69a;
}

.btn-floating:before {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.btn-floating.btn-large {
  width: 55.5px;
  height: 55.5px;
}

.btn-floating.btn-large i {
  line-height: 55.5px;
}

.btn-large {
  height: 54px;
  line-height: 56px;
}

.btn-large i {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.waves-effect {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 1;
  will-change: opacity, transform;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}


.btn-floating {
    background-color: #f44336;
}

#btnSelect {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}

#btnEdit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 80px;
}

#btnDrawPoint {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 140px;
}

#btnDrawLine {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 200px;
}

#btnDrawPoly {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 260px;
}

#btnDelete {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 320px;
}

#btnZoomIn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}



#btnZoomOut {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, excellent job!  I tried it and it works perfect.  I will award you the bounty points.  Now my next step is how to show a text tooltip when they hover over a button.

Comment: Setting the tooltip was easy by the way, its just setting the title attribute of the div...<div id="btnDelete" class="btnMenu title="tooltip here"...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UNCSS](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) with grunt or gulp. [Here is a good guide to get started with UNCSS.](https://addyosmani.com/blog/removing-unused-css/)

I use gulp in certain projects, here is the code for it :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uncss = require('gulp-uncss');
gulp.task('uncss', function() {
  return gulp.src([
      'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
      'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css'
    ])
    .pipe(uncss({
      html: [
        'http://localhost:8000/'
      ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that out.

Comment: AmitJS94, see above update #1.  Uncss did not work.  It broke materialize.css and buttons no longer display/function properly with the results produced by uncss.

Answer (score 0):

If I was in your situation then I would have done following -

1. Grab copy of pure CSS (unified version)
2. Read the CSS carefully and remove unwanted part in same files (so, you can catch if there is fire on CSS file)

Did you try this method?